# Updating Terraform Google provider forces replacement

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to update terraform google provider to `3.58` from `3.55` to add big query deletion protection.

When running a `terraform plan` I get `# forces replacement` warnings:

```
# google_bigquery_table.my_table must be replaced
...
+ deletion_protection = true
...
~ schema              = jsonencode(
          ~ [ # forces replacement
              ~ {
                  ~ fields      = [
                        # (6 unchanged elements hidden)
                        {
                            description = "Location of the data schema."
                            name        = "dataSchema"
                            type        = "STRING"
                        },
                      ~ {
                          ~ type        = "BOOLEAN" -> "BOOL"
                            # (2 unchanged elements hidden)
                        },
                    ]
                  ~ type        = "RECORD" -> "STRUCT"
                    # (2 unchanged elements hidden)
                } # forces replacement,
              ~ {
                  ~ type        = "RECORD" -> "STRUCT"
                    # (3 unchanged elements hidden)
                } # forces replacement,
              ~ {
                  ~ type        = "RECORD" -> "STRUCT"
                    # (3 unchanged elements hidden)
                } # forces replacement,
            ]
        )
```

Can anyone help me understand (a) why am I getting a forced replacement on this update when I haven't changed my schemas and (b) how can I update my google provider without deleting the data in my table.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you specifying the table schema in your config?

Comment: @MattSchuchard yes I define them on the `schema` property in a `google_bigquery_table` resource

Comment: can't you put schema under ignore_changes?

Comment: @NathanRuiz thanks i didn't know ignore_changes existed. Would doing this just kick the problem down the road for the next update though? Or would I keep the schema under ignore_changes indefinitely?

Comment: It will ignore changes made in the schema so as long as it is there it won't cause any update when applying, drawback is: if you ever need to replicate your environment from scratch you will get whatever is set on terraform which may not reflect the actual data. But apart from that it works just fine. More info at https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it seems that Terraform is aggressive on flagging needs replacement.  I am not sure if it is related, but I have seen sometimes a more 'conservative' flagging of this when changing versions of Terraform (by conservative, I mean it appears to try to replace more often - I am unsure if the upgraded versions don't realize that settings that were not previously settable in TF, but are now, are flagged as potentially changed and thus need replacement).  I agree that if your schema hasn't changed, there is no need to replace the resource.

### Solution

Identify the resource as `ignore_changes` by ensuring it is specified in the `lifecycle` block within the resource body.

From the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes):

> The `ignore_changes` feature is intended to be used when a resource is created with references to data that may change in the future, but should not affect said resource after its creation. In some rare cases, settings of a remote object are modified by processes outside of Terraform, which Terraform would then attempt to "fix" on the next run. In order to make Terraform share management responsibilities of a single object with a separate process, the ignore_changes meta-argument specifies resource attributes that Terraform should ignore when planning updates to the associated remote object.

Some example code from that:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ...
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      # Ignore changes to tags, e.g. because a management agent
      # updates these based on some ruleset managed elsewhere.
      tags,
    ]
  }
}
```

Also note that you can use the keyword `all` instead of a list in `ignore_changes`  to ignore all attributes.

Comment: @RobotEyes Do you think that ignore_changes will solve the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure. Adding the schema to ignore indefinitely would mean I cannot update my schema in the future. I'd assume as soon as I remove the schema from the ignore changes block I have the same problem again. Is this correct?

Comment: @RobotEyes  Yes.  Like I mentioned, it seems over upgrades I get an increased 'sensitivity' of this stuff and then I can remove after a new apply (at least usually).  I wish their release notes were a little better to identify the types of changes that this causes problems with.